# Two questions in transferring data from an XML document to SQL Server: an error emerging in the with clause and a concern about datetime

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, datetime

I am new at this so please bear with me. I am using SQL Server and am trying to transfer data from my XML document into SQL Server.

I have two questions.

Question #1: I have an error for 'where'. If I remove the where line completely the error moves onto 'session'.

Question #2: I want the aptly named datetime column to feature a datetime data type. When I look at the xml document though I see that there is a T for what datetime equals. I believe this T symbolizes the word time. I am worried that this T will cause problems since I have never seen the data type datetime in SQL Server having a letter in the middle of the date and time. Is this a possibility? If so what should I do? I assume that I will have to change my data type if there is a problem (what should it be changed to if so?). Changing the xml document itself to remove the T is not an option.

Here is the copy-paste of my query:

```
DECLARE @x xml

SELECT @x = p
FROM OPENROWSET 
    (BULK 'C:\Users\Owner\Documents\congress\House votes\114 congress 2015\Passage\705.xml; , SINGLE_BLOB) AS HouseVote705(p)

DECLARE @hdoc int

EXEC sp_xml_prepare document @hdoc OUTPUT, @x

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/roll', 1)
WITH (
'where' char,
'session' tinyint,
'year' smallint,
roll smallint,
'datetime' datetime)
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument
```

Here is the copypaste of my xml document:

```
<roll where="house" session="114" datetime="2015-12-18T09:49:00-05:00"> </roll>
```

[A screenshot of my query and the xml document I am working with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dstXP.png)

Comment: 1st rule of stackoverflow - you do not paste code as screenshots. 2nd rule of stackoverflow - you DO NOT paste code as screenshots.

Comment: First rule of every programming language- no use of keywords. Second rule of every programming language- better not using keywords even if they seem to be accepted. Rename `where` and `session` with something more meaningful and try again.

Comment: @Sergey Really? I didn't know this was a rule. Sorry I am new here and I have difficulty expressing myself due to being so new at MS-SQL. I did point out the exact parts of the code I was having trouble with in the picture.

Comment: @RuDevel I don't know how I would go about doing that. Altering the XML document is not an option.

Comment: @anang when you paste code as text it's easier for others to read and it can be copy-pasted into ide for various testing

Comment: Hint for Q2: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations

Comment: @RuDevel Thankyou very much! I was so worried about that. It seems the T won't be a problem.

Comment: @anang I'd say you still do not provide a lot for us to reproduce your problem. Break it down to it's minimum even though - of course - this won't be your final solution. With an XML (copy and delete- almost as good as divide and conquer) of 10 Lines or less you'll probably solve your problem yourself. And afterwards you can expand it until you grasped the source of confusion.

Comment: @RuDevel If I understand you correctly I think you're telling me to make a miniature version of the XML document containing very few lines and trying to do it all over again while also providing you with that entire miniature xml's text in the question. I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, use `[ ]` brackets to wrap those reserved keywords, instead of handling these as strings. Like some already stated in the comments, try to avoid the use of keywords for attributes.

Also,  as long as you don't have a XSD (xml schema definition) try to interpret types as little as possible. The `[where]` is definitely not a single character. And are you sure the session will always fit in a `TINYINT`?

For your second question, the `datetime` provided is in Iso8601 format. Just read it as a varchar and convert it afterwards.

Here is an example based on your screenshot:

```
DECLARE @x XML

SELECT  @x = CAST(N'<roll where="house" session="114" year="2015" roll="705" source="house.gov" datetime="2015-12-18T09:49:00-05:00" updated="2016-12-25T10:03:32-05:00"/>' AS XML)

DECLARE @hdoc INT

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @x, '<roll xmlns:xyz="urn:MyNamespace"/>'; 

SELECT [where] AS DocWhere
, [session] AS DocSession
, [year] AS DocYear
, roll
, CONVERT(datetime2, [datetime], 126) AS DocDatetime
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/roll', 1) 
WITH (
   [where] VARCHAR(MAX)
 , [session] INT
 , [year] INT
 , [roll] INT
 , [datetime] VARCHAR(30)
 )
```

Comment: The brackets worked like a charm! I am not sure what you mean by xml schema definition though. You are right about [where] not being a single character. If I put char(5) in then that will make it into 5 characters right? As for session, I interpreted it, like all the other columns in the with clause, as being attributes because their values will never change. I plan to add elementslater. For datetime someone else said the T is fine so I don't think that will be an issue. Looking at your code am I right in thinking that you re-named the columns without changing the xml document?

Comment: MS SQL is usually able to deal with ISO8601 natively as datetime (as it is in the question), it did on my tests with the provided XML.

Comment: Char(5) should work if the length is never longer than 5 characters. SQL Server should be able to convert the datetime from iso8601 (including the T) by itsself, just remember how to explicitly convert the value, in case you get something nonstandard. Yes, those are just column aliases, so your xml will not be changed.

Comment: excellent! I don't need aliases for now. I will figure out how to rename the columns after I complete the data transfer so I don't run into keyword issues in the future. This was very helpful! Using this I can copy paste a lot of the code I'm making for my other data transfers. I have 200ish xml docs left to go! Thankyou everyone!

Answer (score 1):

As in your other questions: `FROM OPENXML` is outdated and should not be used anymore (rare exceptions exist)...

Rather use the modern *XML methods* for this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<roll where="house" session="114" datetime="2015-12-18T09:49:00-05:00"> </roll>';

SELECT @xml.value(N'(/roll/@where)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS roll_where
      ,@xml.value(N'(/roll/@session)[1]',N'int') AS roll_session
      ,@xml.value(N'(/roll/@datetime)[1]',N'datetime') AS roll_datetime
```

The result

```
roll_where  roll_session    roll_datetime
house       114             2015-12-18 14:49:00.000
```

### UPDATE *hundreds of files*...

If this is a one time action it doesn't matter how you do this. This can be slow, ugly and dirty - as long as your result is correct...

Do you have the file paths/names in a table or are they following a computable schema? It should be easy to use a `CURSOR` or a `WHILE` to work this down in a loop.

You can use the command which you use on top of your question to load the XML's content directly into the variable `@xml` and use `SELECT a,b,... INTO #tmpTbl FROM...` to write the content of all your files in one go into a staging table.

In most cases it is best, to create the whole statement as string (don't forget to double all quotes!) within your loop and use `EXEC` to execute this. Otherwise you'd get a problem with the file's path in `OPENROWSET`...

Comment: Thankyou for telling me about the more modern method. Unfortunately I have to perform this action for over 300 xml documents. These documents are all identical in terms of columns but not identical in values. So what I need is the most streamlined method possible to do this. I was considering copy pasting my code for all those documents while making tiny changes for each one. If I use this method I will have to do a lot more changes because I'll be inputting the values.

Comment: I am having a hard time following. The xml documents are on my computer and they mostly have the same file path since they end up in the same folder. I do not know what a computable schema is neither and have never hard of the cursor keyword. I should also note that the xml document that I used for this is no longer supported by my source. I therefore moved onto a different source (which I managed to save on my computer). In working with these new files I encountered an issue which is in my most recent question.

Comment: @anang So - just to get this clear: Your most recent question shows the actual XML you have to deal with? Many of these files are situated in one directory and you want to read them one after the other (all same in structure but different in data?) and write the data into a table. Correct so far?

Comment: Sort of. Everything you said is true except that I only have half of all necessary files. I already have all the 2015 files (that I put in the 2015 folder). The other half will take me two hours to put on my computer. They are the 2016 files that I will put in the 2016 folder. the 2015 and 2016 files all have the same structure though, but the 2016 ones will live in a slightly different directory.